# Google Android Management API - mapping Map<K,V> fields

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, rdbms

I need to map the objects from google android management api endpoints with hibernate https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest. Many of those objects contain Map<K,V> fields (30+) which are messy to map with Hibernate, at least for me.

For now, i am storing everything as JSON but if I want to do relational, is there an alternative to creating an entity for every object field and mapping it conventionally?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.